# Testlink 1.9 and Jira integration error

Tags: integration, jira

I've faced with Testlink  issue - at Reports and Metrics->Failed Test Cases - unable to view any result - fatal error at right frame

`Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'ADODB_hsql.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear;.;C:\wamp\www\testlink_1_9_RC1\lib\functions\;C:\wamp\www\testlink_1_9_RC1\third_party\') in C:\wamp\www\testlink_1_9_RC1\lib\functions\common.php on line 96`

Also I've add to custom_config,inc.php:

```
$tlCfg->config_check_warning_mode = 'SILENT';   
$tlCfg->api->enabled = TRUE;             
$g_attachments->order_by = " ORDER BY id ASC "; 

$g_interface_bugs = 'JIRA';
```

And configure jira.cfg.php:

```
define('BUG_TRACK_DB_HOST', 'localhost:8100');

/** The name of the database that contains the jira tables */

define('BUG_TRACK_DB_NAME', 'jiradb');

/** The DB type being used by jira */

define('BUG_TRACK_DB_USER', 'admin');

/** The DB password to use for connecting to the jira db */

define('BUG_TRACK_DB_PASS', '<admin_password>');

/** link of the web server for jira */

define('BUG_TRACK_HREF', "http://localhost:8100/secure/Dashboard.jspa");

/** The DB type to use for connecting to the bugtracking db */

define('BUG_TRACK_DB_TYPE', 'hsql');
```

Note: as you can see I've use Jira use hsql

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Try asking at https://answers.atlassian.com/. This seems to be an internal issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can only use a DB TYPE that is supported by ADODB, and from the error messages seems that hsql driver does not exists.
My suggestion is: why using stackoverflow instead of www.teamst.org ?